# C sscanf() force number input

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

I'm trying to use sscanf() to validate commandline input

I want only things like 1, 0.1, 0.111 to go through,
not a12 12a or 1.2a

I tried

```
if (sscanf(input, "%f", &val) != 1) { // to check for 1 successful conversion
      printf("invalid input");
}
```

but it seems like I'm letting invalid inputs go through as well.

Any advice?

Comment: Don't call `scanf()` twice. The `if()` is not testing whether the first one was successful, it's doing a second scan after it.

Comment: that's not actually what my code looks like. I just wanted to help the reader understand. I only have the second line

Comment: Obviously it didn't help me understand. Post your actual code, the result you expect, and what you're getting instead.

Comment: `scanf` is not a strict parser. It's just a quick and dirty parser that's useful for throwaway code. If you want strict parsing, take a look at `strtok`, `strtol`, and `strtod`.

Comment: I would suggest accepting the input, whatever it is, as a string, and then testing it.

Comment: @user3386109 if I decide to use `strtof` how can I check for valid number (int or double/float) using the `*endptr` after conversion?

Comment: Search for `[c] strtof endptr`

Answer (score 3):

When `sscanf(input, "%f", &var)` encounters the input `12a` or `1.2a`, it stops at the invalid input part, leaving the remaining characters available for reading by a subsequent format code.

Consider that the following strings have invalid characters for floating point numbers following a valid number:

- `1.0 2.0` (a space)
- `1.0, 2.0` (a comma)
- `1.0a 2.0` (a letter)

Spaces and commas look OK to our human parsing engine; the machine floating point parsing simply stops when an invalid character is found, whether it is a human acceptable space or comma, or an ugly letter.

If you want to ensure that a floating point number is not immediately followed by garbage, you could use something like:

```
n = sscanf(input, "%f%c", &var, &ch);
if (n == 1 ||
     (n == 2 && (ch == ' ' || ch == ',' || ...))) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote?  Down votes are fine, but, please, give a reason.

Comment: i upvoted not sure who down voted.. what if there is I want to take account for garbage before the float?

Comment: Garbage before the `float` will prevent the `%f` conversion from succeeding, and `sscanf` will return 0.

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf` is not your friend, here.  Even if you check the result to
ensure that you read one whole argument successfully, that doesn't
really guarantee that the input is valid in a meaningful sense.

Given input like:

```
1!!!1!oneone!
```

the `%f` parsing will stop (but succeed) after reading the first `1`,
and leave the read pointer at the following `!`.  This may not be what
you consider "valid input".

If anything on the same line is to be considered garbage, then it gets
difficult, because `scanf` doesn't distinguish between spaces and
newlines.  Perhaps try something like this:

```html
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float val;
    char c;
    if (sscanf(argv[1],"%f%c",&val,&c)!=1)
    {
        printf("invalid input");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

now it will validate all commandline input if it's floating number input or not.